# Quick actions - can they be expanded by default?

Tags: lightning, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

When a user first views a Case, the quick action menu is collapsed. It expands when they click on it. While I think this makes sense, the users want it expanded by default. Can this be set? Example pictures.

[image]

[image]